# How can i retrieve a specfic details news in my ionic4 app

Tags: angular, ionic3, ionic4

I have news ionic4 app and i listed all the news from firestore in a page ,
the thing that i wanted is when i click on one of thses news i want to show details in page of details 
how can i do that ? (i think that must by passing id parameter but i didn't how do this )
please help me

my code is showen below :

**films.page.html** (this page is the home page)

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-toolbar color="#9b59b6">
    <ion-title id='raas'>الرئيسية</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    <ion-content padding>
        <ion-item *ngFor=" let count of data">
          <h5>{{count.title}}<button >المزيد</button>

            <img src="{{count.image}}">
          </h5>

        </ion-item>

</ion-content>
```

**films.page.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, DoBootstrap } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFirestore} from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-films',
  templateUrl: './films.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./films.page.scss'],
})
export class FilmsPage implements OnInit {
  data: any;


  constructor(public db: AngularFirestore, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllPosts().subscribe((data) => {
        this.data = data;
        console.log(data);
    });
  }
  getAllPosts(): Observable<any> {
    return this.db.collection<any>('123').valueChanges ();
  }

}
```

**film-details.page.ts** (this page is for details)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFirestore} from 'angularfire2/firestore';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-film-details',
  templateUrl: './film-details.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./film-details.page.scss'],
})
export class FilmDetailsPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(public db: AngularFirestore) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**tabs.router.module.ts** (this is my routes)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'films',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../films/films.module#FilmsPageModule'
          },
          {
            path: 'detail/:id',
            loadChildren: '../film-details/film-details.module#FilmDetailsPageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'people',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../people/people.module#PeoplePageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'planets',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../planets/planets.module#PlanetsPageModule'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/films',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Read the documentation please :) https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: the problem is how to passing id that i stored it in firebase to details page

Comment: You are not showing what you have even attempted? But anyway, the documentation shows how to do it. Pass the id as router param, when you are at the detail page, request the details by param you have passed. Assumingly that is what you want. That's well explained in the documentation :)

Answer (score 0):

2 ways to pass id to your details page

1. In you HTML

```
<a [routerLink]="['/detail', count.id]">{{item.id}}</a>
```

I am assuming your count holds the detail id, if not replace count.id with your detail id that you need to pass

2. In you ts

```
goToDetail(film) {
    this.router.navigate(['/detail', film.id]);
}
```